# overloading << operator whilst accessing private elements (friend)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a program that requires me to overload the `<<` operator whilst accessing `private` members of the class. It goes like this:

A.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <ostream>
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

class A {
public:

    A(B* b) {
        this->b = b;
        this->x = 0;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, A& a)
    {
        os << "this is a " << a.x;
        return os;
    }

private:
    int x;
    B* b;
};
```

B.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:

    B(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, B& b)
    {
        os << "this is B " << b.x;
        return os; 
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    B* b = new B(1);
    A* a = new A(b);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

However, this doesn't print `a` and `b`, just the memory address of the two objects. I think it has something to do with the order of operations, but I'm not sure on that.

Also, I can't use `ostream& operator<<()` as an independent function since that would prevent me from accessing the private member of the class.
I could potentially implement a `void print()` inside the class and use that to print the private members, but I don't think that's what my professor has in mind (considering there's already a `void print()` implemented for something else).

Comment: Dereference `a` and `b` using the `*` operator?

Comment: Pointers in C++ shouldn't be used unless you actually need a pointer. Certainly the ones in `main` don't need to be. It's quite possible that the `b` in your class would be better off not being one either, but I can't say from example code. (And while on about best practices, output should accept rvalues and const objects.)

Comment: simply don't use `new` here. Its amazing how many problems that can solve (also your memory leak will be gone)

Comment: `B* b` <- even though you named the variable `b` doesn't mean it's an object of type `B`. It's a pointer. Thus you cannot simply call member functions for `B` objects on it, without dereferencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main()`, `a` and `b` are pointers.  This code:

```cpp
cout << a
cout << b
```

Is effectively calling this:

```cpp
cout.operator<<(a)
cout.operator<<(b)
```

Because `std::ostream` has a member `operator<<(void*)` for printing a pointer, and all pointers are implicitly convertible to `void*`.  This is why you are seeing memory addresses in the output.  Your custom operators are not being called at all, as they require you to pass actual object instances to `operator<<`, which you are not doing.

You need to dereference your pointers in `main()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    B* b = new B(1);
    A* a = new A(b);
    cout << *a << endl;
    cout << *b << endl;
    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

In this code:

```cpp
cout << *a
cout << *b
```

Since `std::ostream` does not have member `operator<<`s for `A` or `B`, this will effectively call this instead:

```cpp
operator<<(cout, *a)
operator<<(cout, *b)
```

Which will call your custom operators.

Otherwise, simply get rid of the pointers altogether:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    B b(1);
    A a(&b);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

Which will also effectively call this:

```cpp
operator<<(cout, a)
operator<<(cout, b)
```

Thus calling your custom operators.

---

On a side note, your custom operators should be accepting references to `const` `A`+`B` objects, eg:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a)
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const B& b)
```